# Want javascript in Acrobat to save to filename generated by my code

Tags: javascript, save, acrobat

I can use app.execMenuItem("SaveAs") and write in the filename I want to save it as. But I'd rather it had a filename I generate in the code.

```
var pp = this.getPrintParams();
pp.interactive = pp.constants.interactionLevel.full;
pp.printContent = pp.constants.printContents.doc;
var place = this.getField("Locations").valueAsString;
var userID = this.getField("Username").valueAsString;
var pType = this.getField("formType").valueAsString;
var fileName = "iii-"+pType+"-memo_sierra-"+userID+".pdf";
if (place == "dt" || place == "cl") {
 this.flattenPages(0,0,2); 
 this.deletePages(1);
} else if (place == "la") {
  // Law print Memo only
  this.print(false,0,0);
} else {
  // Anderson so print Memo and Agreement
 this.print(pp);
}
//app.execMenuItem("SaveAs");
this.saveAs(this.fileName);
```

Answer (score 0):

The last line should read...

```
this.saveAs(fileName);
```

However, the "saveAs" method can only be executed during a batch or console event or in a privileged context.